# When, what, and which to Evolve?

Tags: pokemon-go

I am level 10 in Pokemon GO and I caught two of the same Pokemon very recently, both of which can be evolved three times.

One Pokemon has a CP of 210 with a moveset of power (10,15). I also have another of the same Pokemon with CP 140 with a moveset of power (10,25).

I need to decide what to evolve. Some people tell me go with CP and the others tell me look at the "bar" (which I do not understand how I can derive implications on what to derive by looking at the Bar above the Pokemon's head because the bar is same for all of that type of pokemon except it is further down for the one with higher CP). Moreover, others tell me I need to evolve both first to see which one is better.

What should one consider before evolving and when should I use the power up button?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you want to evolve when the CP is the higher you can get. You raise the CP by powering it up. The problem is that every time you level up your character, the max CP for your pokemons gets raised. So you can wait indefinitely.

The bar represents the CP a pokemon can get from the minimum to the maximum. If your pokemon has the circular bar filled to the half, then that pokemon, for your level, can have the double of CP (powering it up or capturing a new one).

Comment: SysDragon thank you! So I should dis-regard move sets when I consider evolving and only look at CP.

Comment: @WorriedGuest Yes, that's it